# WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS is undefined?

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, internationalization

WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS is referenced in  in a call to WideCharToMultiByte by the inline method GetAnsiStringSize().

But the above symbol is undefined and I can't figure what I'm supposed to do to define it.  Google searching and MSDN failed to uncover any clues, other than it's a standard symbol for the above function call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS` is defined in **winnls.h** as

```
#if(WINVER >= 0x0500)
#define WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS      0x00000400  // do not use best fit chars
#endif /* WINVER >= 0x0500 */
```

so you'd better check what the value of `WINVER` is in your app/project/solution

Answer (score 0):

`#include <windows.h>` is all that should be needed.

Answer (score 0):

as Edwin wrote... I actually had the very same problem, an I solved it as follows:

1) Go to  http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa383745.aspx  and search for the Value for NTDDI_VERSION that applies to your OS version. For example, for Windows 8 I have: 0x0602

2) In your code type:

```
#define WINVER 0x0602
```

3) The error with WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS  appears to me because of the usage of msclr::interop::marshal_as.... so, finally don't forget to add your headers

Hope this helps for you guys!